# How to change Drawer Indicator with jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu Library?

Tags: android, icons, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

At the moment there is an arrow for navigation drawer indicator, how can I change this? 
Is this supposed to be change in the action bar or the sliding menu?

I've tried this with no luck:

```
sm.setSelectorDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
sm.setSelectorEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to styles-v11 and v14

```
  <resources>
        <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">

            <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
            <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

for the normal styles just put

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sliding menu as an xml view then you might have seen this code:

```
<com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
sliding:viewAbove="@layout/YOUR_ABOVE_VIEW"
sliding:viewBehind="@layout/YOUR_BEHIND_BEHIND"
sliding:touchModeAbove="margin|fullscreen"
sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/YOUR_OFFSET"
sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/YOUR_SCALE"
sliding:shadowDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SHADOW"
sliding:shadowWidth="@dimen/YOUR_SHADOW_WIDTH"
sliding:fadeEnabled="true|false"
sliding:fadeDegree="float"
sliding:selectorEnabled="true|false"
sliding:selectorDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SELECTOR"/>
```

Give the selectorDrawable, the image you want to set for the drawer indicator.

Comment: How can i use this xml?